# How do I transpose a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix in the following format :

```
row.names GSM362168       GSM362170         GSM362171   GSM362175     GSM362177
133        5.053517        5.391068         5.363335    5.349085       5.682385 
135        6.575044        6.571494         6.282546    6.514062       9.751356 
141        5.874980        5.586731         5.558642    5.718945       5.522853
```

And I want it in the following format:

```
row.names    133       135         141
GSM362168 5.053517  6.575044    5.874980
GSM362170 5.391068  6.571494    5.586371
GSM362171 5.363335  6.282546    5.558642
GSM362175 5.349085  6.514062    5.718945
GSM362177 5.682385  9.751436    5.522853
```

I tried using the following command but did not work

```
do.call(rbind, unstack(covcontrol))
```

Comment: You don't want to `unstack`, but transpose. Try `t(covcontrol)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just transpose?

```
t(convcontrol)
```

Comment: Thank you . Sorry it was a silly question . I did not realise it then

Answer (score 4):

You just need to transpose your matrix:

```
R> matrix(1:9, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
R> (d = t(matrix(1:9, 3)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Comment: @PaulHiemstra The British part of me feels the need to apologise ;)

Comment: Nice, 3 correct answers (including the comment answer) in 3 mins. That's what I call support!